# Integrating $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ without using substitution

Tags: integration

in order to solve $\int_{0}^a \sqrt{1+x^2} dx$ someone gave a hint; separating the term into:

(1) $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + x\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

The first one is done. But how to tackle $x\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ (without substitution!)? I'd tried integrating by parts, ending with some nonsense. Any hints?

Comment: Why must you avoid substitution?

Comment: Simply because of training other ways/methods.. :)

Comment: Okay $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx+\int x\dfrac{2x}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx$$
By parts
$$\int x\dfrac{2x}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx = x\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx = x\sqrt{1+x^2}-I $$
then 
$$2I=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx+x\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Comment: cool, thanks! That's really nice.

Comment: Your welcome.!.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts to get

$$2\int_0^a\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}~{\rm d}x=a\sqrt{1+a^2}-\int_0^a\sqrt{1+x^2}~{\rm d}x$$

So now you can relate the two.

Comment: Thank you too as well, now it makes sense :)